# Raspberry Pi is taking the predefined values using the Python code

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

```
import RPi_I2C_LCD
from time import *
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

lcd = RPi_I2C_LCD.LCD()

lcd.set_backlight(True)
lcd.set_cursor(row=0)
lcd.message("DINESH SIR")
lcd.set_backlight(True)

ser=serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty1',baudrate=9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,timeout=1)
while(True):
    x=ser.read()
    print(x)
    if x=="1" or x=="b":
        GPIO.output(19,True)
        print("on")
        lcd.message("ON")
    else:
        GPIO.output(19,False)
        print("off")
        lcd.set_cursor(row=1)
        lcd.message("OFF")
```

When I'm trying to connect hc-05 bluetooth module with my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian streach OS, then using the above code, I'm getting the output as follows

```
b ''
off
b ''
off 
b''
off 
b''
off 
b''
off 
b''
off 
b''
off 
b''
off 
b''
```

and so on executing in a loop.

Comment: Are you maybe sending `1`, linefeed, `1`, linefeed?

Comment: we are not getting you what you are talking about linefeed?

Comment: What are you sending to the Raspberry Pi? Your question only complains about what it does in response but there's no indication what you are sending it, or how.

Comment: we are using roboremo app for sending input serial data. My hc-05 bluetooth module is connected and paired to roboremo app. When I'm trying to execute the above python code and when I'm sending data input like, A,a,B,b then it show only the b'' off b'' off. The app name is  
RoboRemoFree Arduino Bluetooth on Play store